# Writing symmetric polynomials in term of elementary symmetric polynomials...

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Fix a degree $L>0$. Consider $m$ many variables $x_1, x_2, ..., x_m$, where $m\geq L$. We have the elementary symmetric polynomials
$$ e_1=\sum_j x_j, \ \ e_2=\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j, \ \ e_3=\sum_{i<j<k}x_ix_jx_k, \ \ ...$$
Now given $j_1\geq j_2\geq ...\geq j_r\geq 1$ such that $j_1+j_2+...+j_r=L$, let $f_J$ be the homogeneous symmetric polynomial of degree $L$ that is generated by $x_1^{j_1}x_2^{j_2}...x_r^{j_r}$ (i.e. $f_J$ is the symmetric polynomial with minimal number of terms that contains $x_1^{j_1}x_2^{j_2}...x_r^{j_r}$). The polynomial $S_{j_1, j_2, ..., j_r}$ of variables $e_1, e_2, ..., e_m$ is defined by (notation here being modified from Hirzebruch's book)
$$ 
S_{j_1, j_2, ..., j_r}(e_1, e_2, e_3, ..., e_m)=f_J(x_1, ...,x_m).
$$
We can write
$$
S_{j_1, j_2, ..., j_r}=\sum_{i_1, i_2, ..., i_s}S_{j_1, j_2, ..., j_r}^{i_1, i_2, ..., i_s}e_{i_1}e_{i_2}...e_{i_s},
$$
where the summation is over all sequences $i_1\geq i_2\geq ...\geq i_s\geq 1$ such that $i_1+i_2+...+i_s=L$. Here $S_{j_1, j_2, ..., j_r}^{i_1, i_2, ..., i_s}$ are coefficients of $S_{j_1, j_2, ..., j_r}$.

Question: Hirzebruch's 1966 book (Lemma 1.4.1) seems to say that
$$
S_{j_1, j_2, ..., j_r}^{i_1, i_2, ..., i_s}=S^{j_1, j_2, ..., j_r}_{i_1, i_2, ..., i_s}.
$$
I checked the first few cases. But how to produce (or where to find) a general proof? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the nonstandard notation. A proof can be found in Egge's book "An introduction to symmetric functions and their combinatorics", Corollary 2.14 on page 36. This says that on the space of homogeneous degree $k$ symmetric polynomials, the basis-change matrix between the elementary basis $e_\lambda$ and the "monomial basis" $m_\mu$ is a symmetric matrix.